# Name newly added worksheets based on variable name, or array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, pdf, worksheet

I have a folder with all the PDFs of our fund managers' monthly statements. I am trying to create a sub that will loop through them all, converting each pdf report into a worksheet in an excel doc. The problem is, the naming conventions of each firm that sends us a statement is very different, so I'm trying to come up with an elegant way to name each worksheet. Here is the code for the first sub that opens the new workbook, sets the path and calls the other sub which actually imports the pdf.

```
Sub newWkbk_callSub()
    Dim PDF_File As String
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks.Add
    wb.SaveAs Filename:="H:\Performance Reports\SMU Quick Endowment Performance Summaries\2017\Supporting Docs\Monthly Manager Statements\Update wksht  " + Format(Now(), "mm-dd-yyyy") + ".xlsx"
    Dim rptName As Variant
    Dim element As Variant
    Dim asOf As Date
    Dim path, sfx, Fund1, Fund2 As String
    path = "H:\Performance Reports\SMU Quick Endowment Performance Summaries\2017\Supporting Docs\Monthly Manager Statements\"
    sfx = ".pdf"
    asOf = WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(Now(), -1)

    fund1= path + Format(asOf, "yyyy-mm-dd") + " fund1" + sfx 
    'this is fund 1's naming convention: "2017-02-28 Fund1" 
    fund2 = "something similar to fund1"
    rptName = Array(fund1, fund2)

    'loop through the report names/paths in the array
    For Each element in rptName
        Call Imp_Into_XL(element)
    Next
End Sub
```

Ideally, this will loop through the rptName array, opening each file with it's given path, and then use the following sub to drop the pdf text into a new worksheet:

```
Sub ImportPDF(PDF_File As String)

Dim PDFfile As Acrobat.AcroPDDoc              'access pdf file
Dim wordCount As Acrobat.AcroHiliteList         'set selection word count
Dim PDFpage As Acrobat.AcroPDPage             'get the particular page
Dim PDFtext As Acrobat.AcroPDTextSelect    'get the text of selection area

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim tabName As String


Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set PDFfile = New Acrobat.AcroPDDoc
Set wordCount = New Acrobat.AcroHiliteList


With PDFfile
    .Open (PDF_File)            'open PDF file
    'add workbook sheet
    Set ws = Worksheets.Add(, Worksheets(Sheets.Count))
    tabName = (PDF_File)
    Debug.Print (tabName)   ' Can't just name the tab  the  PDF_file, because it's too long - "H:\areallylongstringofdirectories"

    tabName = Right(tabName, Len(tabName) - 113)
    tabName = Left(tabName, Len(tabName) - 4)
    Debug.Print (tabName)     ' I thought about trying to shorten it, but then I run into the problem where the naming convention for each firm's report is different, and the name will be different for a firm reporting "02-2017 Fund1" vs. "Fund2 February 2017"
    ws.Name = tabName


    'and really the code for doing the pdf import is not relevant to my question, this is where I'm trying to get the naming convention right
End Sub
```

The two thoughts I had were (1) that I could name the tab after the name of the variable that calls the string (i.e., fund1 is the variable name, even though it stores the string "H:\etc."), which I looked up, and it seems really complicated, or (2) pass another string variable to the second subroutine as an additional argument (i.e., call Imp_Into_XL(element, tabName), but I'm not sure how that would work into my idea for looping through the array to open the files initially. I feel like if I knew much (or anything, really) about setting up a new class, that  may help, but I'm pretty in the dark on that technique.

This is a very specific problem, and it's a tad hard to describe, so I would  really appreciate any insight on how to solve it, or if you have any ideas that I haven't thought of that would accomplish the same thing, I'm all ears.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this appears to be a design question, not a coding question.

Comment: Note also this is improper variable declaration: `Dim path, sfx, Fund1, Fund2 As String`. Only `Fund2` is explicitly a `String` type. The rest are `Variant`.

Comment: Option 1 (naming it based on the *variable name* is essentially not possible in VBA which doesn't support any sort of introspection like that). Instead of using an array of paths, use a dictionary where keys=paths$ and values=tabName$?  Otherwise, I'd agree with Comintern this is more of a design question than a specific code *problem*.

Comment: Then again, if you're going to name it after the variable (e.g., "fund1"), the variable name isn't going to change, so why not just hardcode a constant string and use that as the tab name always?

Comment: The array looks like (fund1, fund2, etc.) as the element variable loops through, it gets assigned to each of these variable names, which are in turn assigned to some path. So you're right, it may not work.

Comment: I'm wondering if I hardcoded a string, how would I use the For loop to call that string each time it opened a new worksheet?

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting variable data from clients that you need to standardise there are IMO 3 ways to deal with it:

1) Enforce some rules. Make your client supply their documents with a specified name format. You control their data and they know that, there is some room for negotiation, this way your code can be fairly uniform.

2) You hardcode a bunch of If statments & other logic - knowing the file names you receive - to change the file names to something acceptable to your code, then you run your sub with these rules and file names.

3) You sucumb to corporate madness and spend the rest of your days fruitlessly coding to accomodate the next new customers naming convention demands :)

I'd go for option one.